# Delphi 11.2 Cannot Compile Firemonkey for Win32 Release

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

Running windows 10 21H2.
Just upgraded to Delphi 11.2 (from 11.1). In fact, I installed it initially, then when the problem occurred, I re-installed taking the option this time to remove registry entries. I ran the Patch and cleanup both times.
On both occasions, I now find that I cannot successfully compile any Firemonkey project for Win32/Release.
Error message is: `F2613 Unit 'FMX.Types' not found.`

Projects compile OK for Win64 debug or release, and for Win32 debug.
I get the same result if I create a new multi-device application with just a "blank" form.

My Win32 Library path is:

```
C:\MyStuff\$(Platform)\$(Config)
C:\MyStuff
$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release
$(BDSUSERDIR)\Imports
$(BDS)\Imports
$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Dcp
$(BDS)\include
$(BDS)\Source\ToolsAPI
$(FLEXCELVCLNT)\Packages\d11\Win32\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReports\LibD28
```

Update: I can make the compile problem disappear by moving "$(BDSLIB)$(Platform)\release" to the top of the Library path. The IDE still flags the problem line with a red "!". I can make that disappear by moving "$(BDS)\source\fmx" to the top of the browsing path. But this makes no sense and I really want "my stuff" to take precedence.

Comment: Your *stuff* should be after the IDE's internal ones. It needs to be able to resolve them before they're used, in the same way that a function has to be declared before it is used. You should not interfere with the out-of-the-box ordering of internal files. They're ordered first for a reason.

Comment: @Ken Thanks for that. You are undoubtedly right, I've just always done it the other way just in case there was a name collision - which one strives to avoid.

Comment: If there's a name clash, you can resolve it using the unit.name syntax or by reordering your uses clause.